# Input Fields aren't aligning in form-inline or form-horizontal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I really need some help here. I've been messing with this form all day and I can't get these boxes to show where I need them to. I'll include a picture below of how I *want* it to look. I've been trying different things with `form-inline` and `form-horizontal` but it's just not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Here's some of what I've been trying:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4>Shipping Address</h4>
                        <hr>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4>Contact Info</h4>
                        <hr>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="inputKey" class="col-md-2 control-label">First Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputKey" placeholder="First Name">
                            </div>
                            <label for="inputValue" class="col-md-3 control-label">Email Address</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" placeholder="Email Address">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

Comment: Could you post some of your code?  Hard to say what isn't working unless we can see what you have.

Comment: how do you want them aligned? all in one column?

Comment: The picture shows how I want the boxes aligned. The headers in a row, first name & email in a row, etc

Comment: do you have any css used so far?

Comment: no custom css, just the bootstrap classes

Comment: You have 13 columns, your max should be 12 for this: the second label has `col-md-3`. Try using `col-md-2.` (Also, there shouldn't be any need for a `row` either: see [Horizontal Form](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal))

Comment: vanburen, I've tried combination of all different numbers, including what you said to try. The spacing and size of the boxes aren't working like they would normally outside this form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure you're using the correct rows/cols, and don't use `form-horizonal` along with the grid columns.

```
<form class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h4>Shipping Address</h4>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h4>Contact Info</h4>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputKey" class="col-md-2 control-label">Key</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputKey" placeholder="Key">
                </div>
                <label for="inputValue" class="col-md-2 control-label">Other</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" placeholder="Value">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputKey" class="col-md-2 control-label">State</label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSt" placeholder="ST">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" placeholder="Zip">
                </div>
                <label for="inputValue" class="col-md-2 control-label">Other</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" placeholder="Value">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/e92EivkCaq